# Структура базы данных

Tags: joomla, php, kohana, mysql

В общем имеется интернет-магазин на Joomla!, довольно уже взрослый - 40000 товаров и 3000 - 5000 посетителей в день. При таких нагрузках сайт жестоко тормозит и сильно перегружает сервер. Появилось желание оптимизировать движок. Помогло, но не надолго - через некоторое время товаров добавилось, посетителей тоже и всё вернулось на свои места.

Теперь думаю перенести его на фреймворк kohana. Шаблоны почти все уже готовы, остались мелочи (я немного и верстальщик ещё), уже есть на 10% работающая версия сайта (1 месяц работы по 12 часов в день) с частично перенесённой базой (вручную копировал :-| позиции). Теперь нужно правильно перенести позиции товаров из базы данных в джумле в новую базу данных для коханы (с контроллерами и моделями у меня проблем не возникает, напишу за вечер всю логику). Так же и с категориями/новостями/пользователями.

Уже столько времени ковыряю джумловскую базу - не могу понять структуры. Есть ли какие-то ресурсы/книги/статьи где почитать про неё можно?

P.S. Сайт не мой, я просто наёмник, поэтому выбор джумлы - не моя ошибка.
Кстати, если кому интересен процесс переноса - ничего напрямую перенести нельзя, всё заново писать пришлось, ну и копипаста из исходного кода в браузере, как без этого.

Comment: Интересно, почему же перенести нельзя?

>..вручную копировал :-| позиции..  
>..Теперь нужно правильно перенести позиции товаров из базы данных..

как-то запутанно у вас всё.

Comment: Вручную я просто для тестов делал, несколько позиций выборочно взял, чтобы заказчику хоть что-то показать рабочее... 
Мне хочется понять почему и зачем в джумле столько(!) таблиц и столбцов. Что там лишнее (хотя бы то, что связи между категориями и товарами организованы через 2(!) промежуточные таблицы, + что для товаров, что для категорий ещё дополнительно есть по 2 таблицы, назначения которых я не понимаю). И на основе этого написать конвертер из базы джумлы в свою.

Comment: Как помню из своей молодости, то на джумле нету готового интернет-магазина, наверняка ставился какой-нибудь компонент. Тогда уже Вам надо не в документацию джумлы, а в документацию этих компонентов лезть.
Собственно и обилие этих компонентов засоряют всю бд.

Comment: надо не в документацию джумлы, а в документацию этих компонентов лезть
Спасибо, буду дальше копать, значит...

Comment: Нашел! Оказывается это virtuemart Вот ссылка, может кому-гибудь пригодится :-) http://kdt.biz.ua/archives/4246

Answer (score 1):

Вдруг кому понадобилась [схема БД joomla 1.5](http://www.joomla-docs.ru/images/e/e7/Joomla_1.5_database_scheme.png) в 2к17

[image: схема БД joomla 1.5]